# How to correctly use the spinner

Tags: java, android, spinner

I have some items (strings) in my spinner and when I select one of these items, I want back an associated value, for example:

If I select SAE 1020, it returns me 250.0
If I select E-155, it returns me 300.0

The value is suposed to be shown in a EditText, but the only value I see is 250.0.
After all, this value should be sent to the next Activity (I also do not know if I'm doing the transfer correctly).

What is happening? What can I do?

Code:

```
package com.mateus.ligacoestubulares;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class Dados extends AppCompatActivity {

String [] AçoMontante = {"SAE 1020", "E-155"};
String [] AçoBanzo = {"SAE 1020", "E-155"};
String [] EspessuraT1 = {"0,75 mm", "0,90 mm", "0,95 mm"};
String [] EspessuraTo = {"0,75 mm", "0,90 mm", "0,95 mm"};
EditText campoFy1;
EditText campoFyo;
EditText campoT1;
EditText campoTo;
EditText normalM;
EditText normalB;
EditText momentoB;
EditText teta;
Button next;
Intent intentNext;
Bundle bundle;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dados);

    Spinner spinnerMont = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerM);

    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, AçoMontante);
    spinnerMont.setAdapter(arrayAdapter1);

    campoFy1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fy1);

    String montStr = spinnerMont.getSelectedItem().toString();

    String fy1 = Double.toString(choiceM(montStr));

    campoFy1.setText(fy1);

    Spinner spinnerBanzo = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerB);

    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, AçoBanzo);
    spinnerBanzo.setAdapter(arrayAdapter2);

    campoFyo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fyo);

    String banzoStr = spinnerBanzo.getSelectedItem().toString();

    String fyo = Double.toString(choiceB(banzoStr));

    campoFyo.setText(fyo);


    next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.prosseguir);
    intentNext = new Intent(Dados.this, ConferenciaDosDados.class);

    next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String resistenciaM = campoFy1.getText().toString();
            String resistenciaB = campoFyo.getText().toString();
            bundle.putString("fy1",resistenciaM);
            bundle.putString("fyo",resistenciaB);
            intentNext.putExtras(bundle);
            startActivity(intentNext);

        }
    });
}

public double choiceM(String str) {

    Double f1 = 0.0;

    if (str.equals(AçoMontante[0])) {
        f1 = 250.0;
    } else if (str.equals(AçoMontante[1])) {
        f1 = 300.0;
    }
    return f1;
}

public double choiceB(String str) {

    Double fo = 0.0;

    if (str.equals(AçoMontante[0])) {
        fo = 250.0;
    } else if (str.equals(AçoMontante[1])) {
        fo = 300.0;
    }
    return fo;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. This code is working as you want it to.

```
        String [] AçoMontante = {"SAE 1020", "E-155"};
        String [] AçoBanzo = {"SAE 1020", "E-155"};
        String [] EspessuraT1 = {"0,75 mm", "0,90 mm", "0,95 mm"};
        String [] EspessuraTo = {"0,75 mm", "0,90 mm", "0,95 mm"};
        EditText campoFy1;
        EditText campoFyo;
        Button next;
        Intent intentNext;
        Bundle bundle;
        String montStr,banzoStr, f1,fo;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            campoFy1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fy1);
            campoFyo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.fyo);
            Spinner spinnerMont = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerM);
            Spinner spinnerBanzo = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerB);
            ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter1 = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, AçoMontante);
            ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, AçoBanzo);
            spinnerMont.setAdapter(arrayAdapter1);
            spinnerBanzo.setAdapter(arrayAdapter2);
            spinnerMont.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int i, long l) {
                    montStr = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(i);
                    if(montStr == "SAE 1020"){
                        f1 = "250.0";
                    }
                    else if (montStr == "E-155"){
                        f1 = "300.0";
                    }
                    else{}
                    campoFy1.setText(f1);
                }
                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

                }
            });


            spinnerBanzo.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int i, long l) {
                    banzoStr = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(i);
                    if(banzoStr == "SAE 1020"){
                        fo = "250.0";
                    }
                    else if (banzoStr == "E-155"){
                        fo = "300.0";
                    }
                    else{}
                    campoFyo.setText(fo);
                }
                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

                }
            });


            next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.prosseguir);
            intentNext = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Second.class);

            next.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    String resistenciaM = campoFy1.getText().toString();
                    String resistenciaB = campoFyo.getText().toString();
                    bundle.putString("fy1",resistenciaM);
                    bundle.putString("fyo",resistenciaB);
                    intentNext.putExtras(bundle);
                    startActivity(intentNext);

                }
            });

        }
```

Also, instead of bundles, you can just use private static variables to pass the value.
set `f1` and `fo` as

`private static String f1,fo;` instead of `String f1,fo;`.
And call them in another activity as `Dados.f1` or `Dados.fo` [ Dados here is your current activity ]